# How to send copied text to a text file using pywinauto?

Tags: python, copy, pywinauto

I have copied a text from my software using pywinauto. Unfortunately, I don't know how to paste that to a text file. The following is the code that I wrote:

The last line of the code is not working as it should not. However, that is what I should do. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

````
pywinauto.mouse.double_click(button='left', coords=(820,168))
pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('^c')
f= open("trial.txt","w+")
f.write(pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('^v'))```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're trying to paste the contents of clipboard, but there is no visual area to paste.

`f.write()` will accept text through a variable or, by passing some text. Invoking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is a GUI operation, which can't replace the text in `f.write()`

You can use [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) module to access the clipboard contents.

```
import pyperclip
"""yourcode"""
f.write(pyperclip.paste())
f.close()
```

You can also programatically copy something to system clipboard using pyperclip.

```
pyperclip.copy("This is a text copied to clipboard from Python script!!")
```

You can now check the contents by invoking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in some GUI application like notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try send it `hotkey`

```py
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','v')
```